# LWC Flexible Wire to Get Fields From Multiple Object

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire

I have a LWC that passes email and customerId (a custom field) to an Apex class that retrieves customer information from an external system. The LWC is working fine on a Lead Record Page.

We have the same customer Id field on Contact record as well. So, I would like to make this component flexible so that it can be used on Lead as well as Contact record page.

Is there a way to get this work? I would like to use the same component on Lead Record Page AND Contact Record Page.

Here is the JS code from the LWC:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import {getRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import LEAD_EMAIL  from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Email';
import LEAD_CUSTID   from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.CustId__c';
import profileInfo from '@salesforce/apex/GetProfileData.getCustInfo';

export default class ProfileData extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    result = {};
    profileData = {};
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [LEAD_EMAIL, LEAD_CUSTID]})

    wiredRecord({data, error}) {
        if(data) {
            const { fields } = data
            Object.keys(fields).forEach(item => {
                let value = fields[item] && fields[item].value
                this.result = { ...this.result, [item]: value}
            })
        } else if (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
        
        if(!(this.result.CustId__c == null && this.result.Email == null))  {
            profileInfo({custId: this.result.CustId_c, email: this.result.Email})
            .then( result => {
                this.profileData = result;
            })
            .catch (error => {
                this.error = error;
            });
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can try

1. Using the target configs like below you can provide a configuration option for the admin to choose between lead and contact

   ```
    <targets>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
   </targets>
   <targetConfigs>
     <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage, lightning__HomePage">
        <property name="sobject" datasource="Lead,Contact" type="String" />
     </targetConfig>
   </targetConfigs>
   ```

check for the file format [here](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc/blob/develop/es-space-mgmt/main/default/lwc/customerList/customerList.js-meta.xml)

For the above, you need an `@api` property in your controller. For example, it will be `@sobject` in your js controller.

2. Now you will have to import everything to your controller like below

   `import LEAD_EMAIL  from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Email';`

   `import LEAD_CUSTID   from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.CustId__c';`

   `import CONTACT_EMAIL  from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Email';`

   `import CONTACT_CUSTID  from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.CustId__c';`

Then just in the `constructor()` conditionally populate a variable based on `sobject`property.

```
fields;
@sobject;

constructor() {
   super();
   if(sobject === 'Lead') {
      this.fields = [LEAD_EMAIL, LEAD_CUSTID];
   }
   if(sobject === 'Contact') {
      this.fields = [CONTACT_EMAIL, CONTACT_CUSTID]
   }
}

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: '$fields'})
```

The above will only work to a certain extend. You will end up with a lot of imports if you have many such fields.

A better alternative is to use [CMDT](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/custom_metadata_types_dec/cmt_create) (Custom Metadata Type) for this and use apex controller.

If you need help with code, check this [component](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc/tree/develop/es-space-mgmt/main/default/lwc/customerList) from one of Sample App Gallery Apps.

Comment: Hi  Mohith, Thank you for the suggestion. I am getting the following error message when I try this: "Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined"

Comment: Can you share which lines by sharing the code? Your variable just be undefined

Comment: I needed just one little change - like this:

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: '$fields'})

Now, I am able to use the component on both Lead and Contact. Thank you for your help Mohith.

Comment: ah yes forgot about that reactivity :) Good work!!!

Comment: Super answer @MohithShrivastava! This helped me, many thanks!