# Import field values from two objects at a time into LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lwc-wire-adapter

I need to import field values of the current record and a specific field from the current user. A similar to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/333253/lwc-flexible-wire-to-get-fields-from-multiple-object), but needs to import the data at a time from two objects into a single LWC component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getRecord` twice. Once for your current record and once for the user.

For your current record, you can follow the example here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-record.html

For the current user, you'll first need to get the user's Id, which you can do like this:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import Id from "@salesforce/user/Id";

export default class MiscGetUserId extends LightningElement {
    userId = Id;
}
```

Once you have the Id you can then get the field you want using `getRecord`.

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage [`getRecords`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-records.html) wire adapter to fetch records of different objects at once:

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getRecords, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import USER_EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Email';
import USER_ID from "@salesforce/user/Id";

export default class GetRecordsExample extends LightningElement {
    @recordId;
    accountName;
    userEmail;
    
    get accountIds() {
        return [this.recordId];
    }
    
    get userIds() {
        return [USER_ID];
    }
    
    @wire(getRecords, {
        records: [
            {
              recordIds: '$accountIds',
              fields: [ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD]
            },
            {
              recordIds: '$userIds',
              fields: [USER_EMAIL_FIELD]
            }
        ]
    })
    wiredRecords({data, error}) {
        if (data) {
            this.accountName = getFieldValue(data.results[0], ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD);
            this.userEmail = getFieldValue(data.results[1], USER_EMAIL_FIELD);
        } else if (error) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that the `data` property of the object returned by the wire adapter holds a `results` property which is an array of records.